# "Can take no other" vs. "can't take other"

Tags: word-order, negation, contractions, no-not

As an ESL I'm not sure if I can use the following sentences:

> You can take no other directions.

I'm using it on giving indications to a foreigner.

Should I use instead:

> You can't take other directions.

Which one do you think it is the most natural/idiomatic?

Comment: What is the context?

Comment: What context are these sentences to be interpreted in? are they to be an order?

Comment: Also, you can say 'You can't take no other directions' which is an actual counter prescribed 'double negative' (as opposed to a logical double negative making a positive). But you don't want to use it as it will mark you as a foreigner trying to speak way too vernacular. I'm just saying.

Comment: Related: [“Does not make changes” or “makes no changes”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61326/does-not-make-changes-or-makes-no-changes), [“There is no rule” vs. “there isn't rule”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9427/there-is-no-rule-vs-there-isnt-rule)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the sentences are quite similar.
You see when we say,

> You can take no other directions.

It is quite similar to

> You can't take **any** other directions.

the above two cases are like showing someone **it is the only direction available.**

But when we say,

> You can't take other directions.

It seems a little different then above two statements. It **Expresses kind of an order**, although it may sound differently depending upon the context in which it is used.

Comment: I have a problem with this. I think it's more idiomatic to say "You can take no other direction" or "You can't take any other direction" (singular) if it is the only direction available.

Comment: "You can't take other directions" has the same meaning as the other two examples, and is no more imperative than them.  However, I'd say *cannot* rather than *can't* in that sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The second is more common, but both are fine.

It's possible that it context they would mean different things, but taken in isolation they sound like they'd have the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with Rohan: "You can't take any other direction (s)" sounds most naturally. I put the "s" in parentheses, because to me, it affects the meaning of the sentence.

"You can't take any other direction" refers to "way" or "route" as in asking for directions to arrive at a specific place.

"You can't take any other directions" refers to following rules or instructions as in according to directions.

It's just a hunch. Maybe I'm mistaken. Would like to know what you all think.

Answer (score -1):

Your second answer would be more appropriate, as in the second sentence is more widely used than the first one.

Comment: You've repeated what Jay says, but added nothing.