# There isn't and there is no

Tags: meaning, contractions, no-not

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“There is no rule” vs. “there isn’t rule”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9427/there-is-no-rule-vs-there-isnt-rule)

If I'm not mistaken, both *"There isn't a storm."* and *"There is no storm."* have the same meaning.

I understand that the first one is the "contraction" of the second one, but what I can't understand is that if it is the contraction of the second, why the is second *"There is no storm"* and not *"There is no**t** storm"*?

Comment: It's a contraction of *There is not a storm*, which is also correct, if odd.

Comment: I know that isn't is the contraction of is not. Maybe I should have answered on other way. Both there is no and there is not are right?

Comment: The contraction of the second sentence in your question would be *There's no storm*.  Both *there isn't a storm* and *there is not a storm* are not incorrect, but sound a bit off.

Answer (score 1):

"Isn't" is a contraction of "is not". (Not "is no".)

The correct long form of "there isn't a storm" is "there is not a storm."

Answer (score 1):

The possibility of using contractions is irrelevant here. OP's examples could be reversed by contrasting *there is not a storm* with *there's no storm* - it's all the same.

In such constructions, *"no"* stands in for *"not any"*. It's possible that with any given formulation, some people might perceive a distinction in either nuance of meaning or "euphony/acceptability". For example...

> There is not a God.
>
> There's not a God.
>
> There is no God.
>
> There's no God.

...but I can't say any of those seem inherently "ungrammatical" to me, or mean anything different.

Answer (score 0):

Because the contraction expands to

- there is not a storm

The meaning is the same even if the wording is different.